# How to bound delimiter size for inline math?

Tags: math-mode, line-spacing, delimiters

I am working on a text with inline math containing large delimiters:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\ sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt $\left(I_A^B\right)$\\ ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

At the same time, I would like to avoid disrupted line spacing. Is there a straightforward way of setting an upper bound to delimiter size (flexible size but only up to a certain limit)? Ideally, this would apply only to the above inline math situation but not to e.g. display math. I case of doubt I'd rather stick to `(I_A^B)` instead.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Font is Latin Modern with base size 12 and single line spacing.

Edit 2: Should have been neater with my MWE. So a real example from my text is something as blown-up as

```
$\left[\tau^{\left(a\right)}\left(k\right)\right]^{-1}=\left.k^{2}  \gamma^{\left(a\right)}\right/\chi^{\left(a\right)}$
```

Comment: in most fonts there will be  at most two sizes that fit within the linewidth so it's quite simple, just don't use `\left(\right)` use `()` and `\bigl(\bigr)`

Comment: I don't see any line-spacing disruption in your current example. However, I'd suggest using `\bigl(`...`\bigr)` instead. In extreme cases, you could consider `\smash{...}`, but this may have the content stick into the surrounding lines.

Comment: I added an analysis of your new example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example doesn't show increased space between baselines. In the following code I set `\lineskip` to a big value (default is zero), in order to emphasize when the enlarging happens: you see that in example 2 it doesn't show.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\lineskip}{10pt} % to magnify the effect

1. \textbf{Incorrect}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\ sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt $\left(I_A^{B^\frac{2}{3}}\right)$\\ ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\bigskip

2. \textbf{Incorrect}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\ sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt $\left(I_A^B\right)$\\ ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\bigskip

3. \textbf{Almost correct}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\ sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt $\bigl(I_A^B\bigr)$\\ ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\bigskip

4. \textbf{Correct}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\ sed diam
nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt $(I_A^B)$\\ ut labore et
dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also clearly see that there is no need for the delimiters to cover the entire height: the fourth example is as clearly delimited as the third one.

Note: I had to resort to 10pt size, because at 12pt size `\big` is the same as normal, with Latin Modern. Here is the picture for 12pt.

[image]

### Addition

Now that you have shown the real formula, here's the example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\lineskip}{10pt} % to magnify the effect

1. \textbf{Incorrect}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
$\left[\tau^{\left(a\right)}\left(k\right)\right]^{-1}=
\left.k^{2}  \gamma^{\left(a\right)}\right/\chi^{\left(a\right)}$\\
ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\bigskip

2. \textbf{Correct}\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\\
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
$[\tau^{(a)}(k)]^{-1}=k^{2}\gamma^{(a)}/\chi^{(a)}$\\
ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\end{document}
```

[image]

The enlargement is still bigger than normal, just for better showing where it happens. It's a mistake using `\left` and `\right` everywhere: the “correct” formula is even better readable than the one with them.

Comment: Grazie mille @egreg :)